# Eps image/plot corrupt using Gnuplot

Tags: linux, gnuplot, gnu, gimp

I am using Gnuplot outputting to eps using the following arguments:

```
set output "filename/eps"
set terminal postscript eps
```

However when I view the eps image in document veiwer is not centered and part of the plot lies outside of the boundaries, and when I view it with gimp, some previous plot appears!

I have no idea what is going on.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Don't know what may happening with your boundaries, but you must make sure, that the file is finished when plotting, i.e. issue a `set output` without filename at the end.

Comment: I kept re-writting in the same file and that, for some reason, messed out the boundaries. Once I re-defined the terminal output and output file it worked fine. Thank you Christoph!

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure, that the output file is finished. If you're working in an interactive terminal, you must use `set output` (without filename) before you can view the image.

If several images are contained in a single file, you haven't set your output file properly.